# How do I start a task and have it run for a set amount of time?

Tags: timers, time

I have a project where I need to turn a 24V solenoid on for a set amount of time, then have it turn off. I am rather new to Arduino and not certain how to do this or really where to start. Ideally the time would be displayed on a LCD screen as well but this is purely aesthetic. Any advice, help, examples ect would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: start with example sketches that blink an LED  ..... these can be found in the arduino IDE

Comment: The online example has explanation: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay

Answer (score 1):

Use `millis();`

Record `millis()` in a `long` variable like below when the solenoid starts
`StartTime = millis();`

to switch off solenoid after 60 seconds you may do

```
if ( (millis() - StartTime)/1000 ) >  60
{
   // switch off solenoid
}
```

enjoy coding.

There are other ways as well to achieve this... but this is being easiest  and you don't have to wait caused by using `delay();`

Comment: Division is a very expensive operation on many Arduinos. It is thus better to write `if (millis() - StarTtime >= 60000)`.

Comment: Hmm.. Good to know that..
But would you explain what do you mean by "Expensive" does it draw more power?

Comment: The AVR MCUs do not have hardware support for division, which is thus done by software, bit by bit, and costs quite a lot of CPU cycles. Power consumption should not be affected, _unless_ you care about it. If you do care, you most likely keep the CPU in sleep mode most of the time, and wake it up only when there is work to do. Then, all the cycles you burn doing non-essential operations keep the CPU awake for longer, and cost energy.

Comment: Hmm... ok . Thanks  for the information Edgar !!